# Updating Angular 7.2 project

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a personal project I have been working on for 3-4 years that I want to update from 7.2.

About a year ago I tried for a few days on my Windows PC going from 7-8/9/10 before I just gave up.

I have a Macbook now, and just wondering if I should just go from 7.2 right to 17 or perhaps jump a few versions at a time?

Any other tips/hints? Thanks

Comment: You should upgrade one version at a time, step by step. Be prepared for breaking changes and incompatible packages.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this site to upgrade your angular step by step:
https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=7.2-17.0

but if your project is not too big you can build a new project and copy your components and update your code. sometimes upgrading takes time because of conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/releases#supported-update-paths), you have to upgrade one version at a time. Since you are 9 versions behind, this will take some time.

You may also have to upgrade your version of NodeJS, if you're using an older version, since only the more recent versions are supported. If you have NodeJS installed directly, I would suggest using something like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) instead, which makes it easy to install and switch between various Node versions.

You can follow the steps in the guide linked by @s_erfani in their answer.